# node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely

Tags: node.js, windows-installer

I can't install node.js (0.8.9). I'm doing it via Setup Wizard and each time at the end of installation I get message "Node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely".

What could it be? Thanks.

Comment: Please post some details of your environment (e.g. "Setup Wizard" probably means some variant of Windows; it will really help to know just which variant you're talking about). It sounds like some sort of permissions problem with one of your directories, but nobody here can verify that or figure out how to fix it without more information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This may help someone in the future. I got a similar message from the installer and found that I could go to command prompt and run the MSI with a command line option to make it create a log file (like `node-v0.10.24-x64.msi /lxv C:\Logs\Nodejs.log`), where you can choose what the log is called and where it goes.

In my case, we are running in an Active Directory domain environment and some of our folders that are normally local are redirected to a network share so they are always there no matter what computer we log into. Mostly for the benefit of our "My Documents" folder.

When looking through the log I found the actual error that I was getting:

- WixCreateInternetShortcuts:  Error 0x80070005: failed to save shortcut '\ad.local\system\users\<myAcctName>\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js\Node.js website.url'
- WixCreateInternetShortcuts:  Error 0x80070005: failed to create Internet shortcut
- CustomAction WixCreateInternetShortcuts returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox).

### Resolution (for me)

Oddly enough, just running an admin escalated command prompt first, and then running the MSI lets it install correctly.

I *think* the difference is that when you double-click on an MSI and it escalates, it runs as `TrustedInstaller` and while that account has access to everything on my box, it does not have network access. When I run an escalated command prompt, it is running as **me**, but already escalated (the MSI never needs to ask for escalation), so it works.

### Final Note:

As of 7/22/2015, the node.js team has finally tracked down the issue with the installer and from 0.12.8 and forward this should be no longer an issue for us. I tested an early version of the installer for them to make sure it worked for me and there were no hitches with the install.

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5849#issuecomment-123905214

As of this writing, 7/30/2015, the current version was still 0.12.7, so x.8 has not yet been rolled out to the masses I guess.

Comment: Thanks for this. Running the .msi from an escalated command prompt did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, I was installing nodejs-v13.14.0 in Windows 7 and had the same issue. Later tried to run through cmd with admin privilege and got installed in the machine.   C:\node-v13.14.0-x64.msi

Answer (score 16):

Avast Antivirus is the culprit in my case. Disabling it allowed the installation to complete successfully.

Additional background on how Avast messes this up is [available in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50428154/17034).

Comment: Same here, no need to disable any component during installation, the AV was messing it up ! Though previous installs did not encounter this issue.

Answer (score 15):

Installing without the `Performance counters` feature made the installation work. All credits go to *joaocgreis* for [the comment on the NodeJS GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4329#issuecomment-169952550).

Comment: I have used your recommendation with elevated privileges command prompt and it worked for me.

Comment: Sometime you many not see the Performance counter, see the video to see it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLsiNamyad4

Comment: @RupakNepali You need to expand the `Node.js runtime` node in order to see the `Performance counters` feature.

Answer (score 11):

I had this error on Windows 7 x64 (node-v0.10.28-x64.msi) and was able to install by choosing not to install the "Online documentation shortcuts" during the Custom Setup part of the installation. Select "Entire feature will be unavailable".

[image]

None of the other solutions worked for me, but I did install as admin and log the output. The logs were not helpful (reported a FatalError, not much else).

Credit where credit's due - I found the answer here: 
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4516

Comment: THIS.  But why?  So weird.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with node 7.1.0-x64 Windows 7 64-bit.

I found that there was

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\_V2Providers\{1e2e15d7-3760-470e-8699-b9db5248edd5}`

in the register on my computer. After I had deleted this entry, node installation passed fine.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxjpLn-Lcps) show all the steps to follow.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue, I ran the msi from an admin command prompt with the logging option:

```
node-v0.12.4-x64.msi /lxv C:\Nodejs.log
```

Inspecting the log showed the following error:

> Product: Node.js -- Error 1714. The older version of Node.js cannot be removed.  Contact your technical support group.  System Error 1612.

Node.js was not listed under Program and Features though, so I ran the **Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter tool** (select *Run now*) at the following site:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall

Stepping through the wizard, selecting the 'trouble with uninstalling' option. The tool then listed 'Node.js' as an installed program. Selecting Node.js and finishing the wizard successfully removed Node.js.

I then ran the msi again from an admin command prompt and the node install succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

I was try to install node-v8.1.4-x64.msi many times in window7 and finally successful.
Please follow below step:--

> step 1:- goto run and type "regedt32.exe".
>
> step 2:- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib
>
> step 3:- delete it (may be some file are not deleted  but all folder s/b delete)
>
> step 4:- Re-install it (Double click on .msi file)
>
> step 5:- Hope this will intalled.

Answer (score 2):

I did not figure out what was the problem, I just copied installed version and update system variable PATH with path to my node.js and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced it turns out its a problem of windows event log service. 
First check if Windows Event Log service is on or not. If not started then to fix it, rename or delete the C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup folder in safemode.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to install it the regular way, but I ended up successfully installing it using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) (a Machine Package Manager built with Windows in mind) and then the [nodejs package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that a file had gone corrupted in the Nodejs directory, by going to the folder "Program files" and giving the folder "nodejs" a new name, I was able to reinstall it properly.

I might add that I couldn´t delete the folder Nodejs because there was a corrupted file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Running command prompt with administrative rights and then running msi worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error because I was trying to install a x86.msi to a 64-bit Win7. Then I changed to the correct x64.msi. It still does not work. I guess it might be permission issue, so I copy the .msi to the C:\Program Files, and install from there, and it succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue multiple(2) times. Finally I disabled **AVAST ANTIVIRUS** program & tried to install Node.js again.

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

For *version:12.16.1* using **Windows 10** I tired many different ways but didn't work. so I do the following ways to make it work.

1. [Install the latest version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Remain the setup file inside /downloads folder
3. Open cmd (Run as Administrator)
4. Run node.js msi file using this command ->
   msiexec /a "../download/node-v12.16.1-x64.msi"
5. Install it without any problem

After installation open cmd

**type > node -v**

**v12.16.1**

Answer (score -1):

Most of the times this issue is coming because of the **antivirus program** which we've installed. First scan the setup file using the antivirus program to make sure it's a virus free file and then stop the antivirus program for few minutes and try to install nodeJS.