# Node.js Setup Wizard ended Prematurely on Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install node-v0.10.35-x86.msi on my windows 32 bit system, it will automatically rolling back at the end...

[image]

I had tried some solutions given in the following link...

[node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472079/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely)

none of them worked for me....

Here is my installer log file of this node.js

https://db.tt/223knP0A

Please provide quick solutions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the following command

`"wevtutil.exe" im "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_etw_provider.man"`

is failing on your setup with the following error:
`ERROR  - Error 0x800706b5: CAQuietExec Failed`

A helpful suggestion on how to fix this issue can be found at http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2010/12/30/troubleshooting-office-installation-failures.aspx:

> This issue can occur if the Windows Event Log service is not running.
> Click on start, search and type in services.msc and hit enter.
> Scroll down to the Windows Event Log service, and ensure it is set to
> automatic. If it is not running right click on it and choose start.
> If you get an error like the following:
>
> Error 4201: The instance name passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data > provider.
>
> Then please check the permissions on
> "c:\windows\system32\logfiles\wmi\RTbackup"
>
> If the system account doesn’t have full control, grant the system account full > control and reboot.
> After reboot check and see if the Windows Event Log service is started in
> services.msc.

Answer (score 5):

Try in cmd :

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\_V2Providers\{793c9b44-3d6b-4f57-b5d7-4ff80adcf9a2}" /s
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\_V2Providers\{1e2e15d7-3760-470e-8699-b9db5248edd5}" /s
```

If one of those exist delete it.
It solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solution is "Windows Eventlog". Run `eventvwr.msc` on the "Run" box, check "Installation" and "Application" pages of the Windows protocol section.

Comment: I rephrased your answer as it was not clearly understandable, especially the "services.msg" part. Could you check if the changed entry makes sense to you (it may take some minute until the updated version is shown as it has to be peer-reviewed)?

Comment: I cant find the windows protocol section in my windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of them but finally I am able to fix by expanding the Node.js runtime node in order to see the Performance counters feature and disabling it.

Following video helped me:
https://youtu.be/dLsiNamyad4?t=2m30s