# node.js installer failing with 'CAQuietExec Failed' and 1603 error code on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows-7, windows-installer

I was trying to install node.js on my Windows 7. But, everytime I am trying to install it gives following error:

```
MSI (s) (A0:64) [20:01:44:207]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=RegisterEventManifest,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="wevtutil.exe" im "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_etw_provider.man")
MSI (s) (A0:F8) [20:01:44:217]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI7B6E.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec
CAQuietExec:  Transaction support within the specified resource manager is not started or was shut down due to an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80071a91: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80071a91: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RegisterEventManifest returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 20:01:44: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (A0:64) [20:01:44:528]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (A0:64) [20:01:44:528]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
```

I have tried following solutions, but neither worked:

[Node.js Setup Wizard ended Prematurely on Windows 7 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896355/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely-on-windows-7-32-bit)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2010/12/30/troubleshooting-office-installation-failures.aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/939399

Can someone please help me here, can give some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v4.1.0-x86.msi

Comment: When I checked this a long time ago I found that unchecking "Event tracing (ETW)" in the feature list worked at that time. [**Please see this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202408/129130).

Answer (score 4):

Run Regedit. Do a search for node.js and node.exe. Remove all entries.

Remove any entries from PATH environment variable.

This condition normally occurs due to an incomplete install or uninstallation of node.js.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar Node.js install failure:

```
Action 13:26:10: RegisterPerfmonManifest. 
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x8007000d: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x8007000d: QuietExec Failed
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x8007000d: Failed in ExecCommon method
CustomAction RegisterPerfmonManifest returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 13:26:10: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

This is from Windows 7 for node-v6.10.0-x64.msi.

The solution for this was to **disable Performance Counters** (under the "node.js runtime" option) during the install.  This is suggested by the `RegisterPerfmonManifest` entry in the install log, and also is [recommended on a Node.js GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4329#issuecomment-169952550) as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. 
After a couple of hours trying to fix it, un-checking "Event tracing(ETW)" did the trick for me. Give it a try.

[image]

Comment: [That workaround worked for me back in the day too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202408/129130).

Answer (score 0):

I did two things:

1. un-checking "Event tracing(ETW)"
2. And services.msc enabled Volume Shadow Copy service I put automatic

I tried all but it´s fix to me.
I hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10

1. cmd.exe "Run as administrator"
2. msiexec /i node-v10.1.0-x64.msi
3. "Custom Setup" disable "Event tracing (ETW)"

PS.
Volume Shadow Copy is Manual - not Running

Check version
1. Run cmd.exe
2. node --version
v10.1.0

Answer (score -2):

For some reason, the vendor has decided to ignore windows installer best practices and shell out to some utility to do the installation work.  It's failing.  You aren't the developer of this install so this isn't really a question for stack overflow.