# Node.js installation (windows installer) terminates prematurely on windows 10 64-bit

Tags: node.js, windows, wix, windows-installer

After going through a windows 10 re-installation due to a windows update crashing my laptop, I was left with re-installing many applications. One of them being node.js. When I tried to install it through the windows installer, I kept getting 'setup wizard ended prematurely because of an error message'. I am not sure what the problem is. I used x64 version which is what my OS is and there is no nodejs folder in program files. When I logged the installation this message popped in a lot of the lines `has no eligible binary patches`. Before the no eligible lines there were error logs such as:

```
'WixSchedInternetShortcuts:  Error 0x8007000d: failed to add temporary row, dberr: 1, err: Directory_'

'WixSchedInternetShortcuts:  Folder 'ApplicationProgramsFolder' already exists in the CreateFolder table; the above error is harmless'
```

If that is not enough information please advice me on how to send the full logs without spamming huge text in the thread. Thank you.

**The MSI log file**:
https://gist.github.com/luki2000/ab00476127d54aaf610d8bda84d40a64

Comment: please find my soln in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278879/node-js-install-fails-on-windows-10-1803/50657402#50657402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maybe try to search the log for "value 3" as explained by Rob Mensching in his blog](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/). Doing so will find the locations in the log file that describe errors of significance.

Many people use **dropbox**, **gdisk** or **similar** to post logs. <del>[Some put it on github](https://gist.github.com/adunkman/4164506)</del> (just a sample log for OP, leaving in for reference). Check that last link, is that the same problem you see perhaps? (search for "**value 3**" as explained above - without the quotes of course). Looks like there is an error creating an Internet shortcut. Perhaps that is a Windows 10 problem? I will take a quick look.

<del>I am betting **Bob Arnson** knows what this problem is outright. He will probably give us the real answer, see below for my workaround.</del>

The correct thing to do overall, would probably be to communicate the problem back to the **Node.js guys** so they can fix the problem once and for all.

**UPDATE**: Maybe see if this answer helps you: **[node.js installer failing with 'CAQuietExec Failed' and 1603 error code on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665592/node-js-installer-failing-with-caquietexec-failed-and-1603-error-code-on-windo/48844249)**. Essentially un-check `Event tracing(ETW)` in the setup's feature dialog - or you can try to launch the MSI from an elevated command prompt.

---

<del>**UPDATE**: There seem to be two Internet shortcuts configured for this MSI in the `WixInternetShortcut table`. I would just create a transform to remove these two shortcuts and try a reinstall. If you feel bold and fearless and like to break the law, you can delete the two rows from the table and just save directly to the MSI itself. This is never the right thing to do if you are a deployment specialists. The original MSI is sacred, but if this is for your own system and you need to get something done, that would work. Then you just install the MSI direct afterwards. Otherwise you can install the transform after creating it with a simple command line:</del>

<del>msiexec.exe /i node-v8.11.2-x64.msi TRANSFORMS="C:\MyTransform"</del>

<del>You can create the transform using [Orca, InstEd or SuperOrca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) or [any commercial tool](http://installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm) that supports creating transforms.</del>

<del>In case you don't know, transforms are little database fragments that are applied to the original MSI (which is also a database under the hood). After the transform is applied the in-memory version of the MSI is the MSI + the changes from the transform.</del>

Comment: Ok I used Rob Mensching's method and created a gist for it. https://gist.github.com/luki2000/ab00476127d54aaf610d8bda84d40a64

I got a value 3 on several occasions, one that spits out as a clear error:

'CAQuietExec:  Error 0xc0000409: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xc0000409: QuietExec Failed
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xc0000409: Failed in ExecCommon method'

Comment: You accepted the answer before I could add the latest change. It looks like the problem is related to event manifest registration. Please see the link I added to another stack overflow answer. It looks like you can just uncheck `Event tracing(ETW)` in the setup's feature dialog.

Comment: Removing Event tracing fixed the problem, Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Have fun coding. Javascript is evil! Just sayin'! ;-).