# Node.js - Cannot Install it is showing an error because of .msi

Tags: node.js, windows-installer

Im having a trouble on installing node.js on my computer **Windows 7 , 64-bit**

here is the error right after ill install

[When installing then this pops up click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdwXn.png)

then, after that this will soon show.

but just before downloading i noticed something unusual.. why is it like corrupt or something. here take a look at the image when it is being downloading

[Prematured etc etc... click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBJDY.png)

[Unusual download Icon click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYwWb.png)

kindly help, i really need to install node.js thanks

Comment: A few things firstly: did you try to re-download and re-run? Does it install on a clean virtual? Do you have a pre-release of something on your PC? (for example Visual Studio). You are not actually running Windows in safe mode, are you?

Comment: Do other msi based installations work without a problem?  You can also open Services.msc and try to start the Windows Installer service and see if it gives an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Old Answer***: This super-messy answer of old has a suggestion that you should probably check: [Node.js installation (windows installer) terminates prematurely on windows 10 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493805/node-js-installation-windows-installer-terminates-prematurely-on-windows-10-64).

> ***Essentially***: Essentially un-check **`Event tracing (ETW)`** in the setup's feature dialog - or you can try to launch the MSI from an
>   elevated command prompt.
>
> Or, [**if you need the Event Tracing, try this pragmatic answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278879/node-js-install-fails-on-windows-10-1803/50657402#50657402).

[image: Custom Installation]

***Deployment Mnemonic***: If further debugging is required, here is a **`deployment "mnemonic"`** (as I call it): what is **`locking`** (in use), what is **`blocking`** (permissions), what is **`corrupt`** (disk, malware, configs, encryption), what are **`unexpected system states`** (disk space, time & date & language settings, licensing, windows patch state, path too long, etc...), what are **`incompatible products`**?

- [**Elaborate Version**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48433935/129130)
- [**Terser Version**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350#49987350)

---

***Links***:

- [node.js installer failing with 'CAQuietExec Failed' and 1603 error code on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665592/node-js-installer-failing-with-caquietexec-failed-and-1603-error-code-on-windo/48844249)
- [SQL Server 2017 installation is stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489985/sql-server-2017-installation-is-stuck/51509075#51509075)

Comment: Asmul , i've changed a lot these few hours.. I upgraded my windows 7 to 10 and it fixed the download still figuring it out why.. but thanks for you effort to answer it works :)

Comment: I can now work with angular and apache cordova.. jeez i badly need to get this node work done.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe do a malware check? Just to be sure? And maybe check if your browser is fully updated (just to be sure). In Chrome and Firefox: Help => About. Glad you are operational! Onwards! :-).

Comment: I deleted the nodejs folder and tried to reinstall after restart. It worked