# nodeJs installation error on windows 10 - error 2203

Tags: node.js, installation, windows-10, windows-installer

I have downloaded version 12 of nodeJs, but unable to install on Windows.

**Error - "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing  this package.
This may indicate  a problem with this package.The error code is 2203"**.

I have tried some solutions like giving permissions to Temp folder in C:/Windows folder, running as Admin although the usual user has full permissions.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Typically you would install it under `C:/Program Files`. Have you tried running the setup as Administrator?

Comment: I haven't looked much at this, but maybe have a look here at [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55201876/129130) with a suggestion to try at least.

Answer (score -1):

> **Error code 2203 basically pops up when the user does not have
> sufficient permissions to install the program to the folder that
> contains the installation point or the temp folder. Make sure that you
> are logged in as an Administrator to install the programs on the
> computer**

Run installation with elevated permission ( try to run a program with admin privilege). This should solve the issue.

Comment: That doesn't help