# Node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I've done everything from these two questions:

[node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472079/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely)

[Node.js Setup Wizard ended Prematurely on Windows 7 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896355/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely-on-windows-7-32-bit)

I've got the log, but I can't tell what's going wrong in it. Here it is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhpRUnYxJGhSzhrd0ZyNHlMTm8/view?usp=sharing

I've also tried installing it with Chocolatey, and I get an error 1603, which, from what I've read is just a generic MSI error that's of no help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when installing NodeJs version 6.9.1 in my 64-bit Windows 7 system.

I set "performance counter" to "Install when required" during installation in the setup wizard.  The installation completed successfully.