# Node.js Setup endes with Prematurely message on Windows 7 32bit

Tags: node.js, windows

I am trying to install node.js **node-v4.4.7-x86.msi** on my Windows 7 Professional (32bit) system, but I get the following error

[image]

I am administrator of system, have full privileges but am unable to install it. I have checked following links as well, what should I do?

[Stack Overflow link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896355/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely-on-windows-7-32-bit)

[Stack Overflow link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472079/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely)

Here is what I have tried:

1. using admin privileges
2. exclude some parts of installation package e.g "Online documentation shortcuts"

Comment: What advice did those links give you, and how did they not apply in your case?

Comment: 1. using admin privileges, 
2. exclude some parts of installation package e.g "Online documentation shortcuts"