# Node JS installation ends prematurely

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation

I noticed there was another question about this elsewhere, but it is a bit dated.  [Here is the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472079/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely)

I am having trouble downloading NodeJS v4.2.4  It goes through the installation process, and then prompts "Rolling back action".  Afterward, it states: "Node.JS Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error."

I created a log file from the .msi but it doesn't come up with anything too interesting.  Really interested in hearing feedback for this.

I tried unchecking Online documentation as stated here: [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959791/5771462)
but to no avail.

Im on Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: try installing as administrator perhaps (that's a long shot) - also, try version 5.4.0 - see if it too fails

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Although, I tried both of those options but to no avail.  :(

Comment: There's absolutely no indication of what the error is? That's a pretty poor installer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the "performance counter" to "only run when required"