# Nodejs - Another installation is in progress

Tags: node.js, windows

System - Win 7 64 bit.
Nodejs - node-v6.9.4-x64.msi

Installation error - Another installation is in progress. You must complete that installation before continuing this one.

Solutions that did NOT work - Run as admin, Run via commandline as admin, [log had same error i saw in installer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616498/6648326), [don't install online docs option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959791/6648326),

Please help me to fix this. Thank you !

Comment: Did you try restarting your machine once?

Comment: @AbhilashRVankayala - No. But, it seems to be the solution to most windows problems :) I'll try and get back soon.

Comment: @AbhilashRVankayala - Thanks. That works. What magic happened ?

Comment: good to know that it worked, this might not be related to your nodejs installation, previously there might have been some other installation which was either in progress or did not exit properly, hence you will not be able to execute any other installation, restarting will just solve that because you indirectly killed that previous unstable installation. Because, it solved your issue, i will post it as an answer, so that i migh tbe useful for others in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will not be an issue with your NodeJs installation, it might be because of your previous installation (might be any other software) which might be still in progress or not exit properly.

To solve your issue, please try restarting your machine once and install. This will indirectly kill your previous unstable installation and allow you to install NodeJs

Comment: Just to add my experience with it. I killed the Adobe Acrobat Update Service running in the background and the installation worked smoothly. No restart was necessary.

Comment: @Jonas Adobe...... Thank you! I never would have figured that out. My blood pressure thanks you.

Comment: Damn ... Thank you @Jonas . Still the same issue and fixed while I was installing nodejs 16 reading your comment.

Comment: Did not work for me. Win11x64

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with '2017-03-21, Version 6.10.1 'Boron' (LTS)'. Restarting my PC solved the issue.

P.S. However, this issue seems to be specific to the NodeJs installer. I tried installing other programs after the NodeJs installation threw up this error and they installed fine (even before the restart).