# InstallForge, run a third party exe from the current directory?

Tags: installation

I am building an installer using InstallForge.

Along with my install, i need to run some Third Party installers, for example, Cuda 9.1.

What I want is to create an installer, and a folder structure like this:

```
Installer.exe
InstallsDir
     -Cuda.exe
     -ThirdpartyInstall.exe
```

Then when my installer runs, it should also run the other two exe files.

In the setup process for InstallForge, it allows you to run commands, which i can use to run the exe files.
There is a command variable: `<installpath>\` that is used to run a file from the path that my programme is installed to.

My question is, is there a similar command that i can use to run a file in the directory that the installer runs *from*?

How can i set a relative link to the current directory using InstallForge setup?

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion. There are many other and [well-established deployment tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) that support these requirements with easy-to-use features. [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) and [Installshield](http://www.installshield.com) may be the best known. The free and open source [WiX](http://www.wixtoolset.org/) also provides this support via its [Burn bootstrapper](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/). Burn is a bit "fiddly". [Some "quick start" links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071758/129130).

Comment: Just a couple of more [Burn links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119157/visual-studio-2017-installer-project-include-vc-2015-redistributable/52121996#52121996). In the yellow section primarily.

Comment: And just [one more link: WiX / Burn as opposed to several commercial tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146749/custom-installer-for-application-in-visual-studio-2017/52159374#52159374). Section "*Deployment*" and onwards. See links for screenshots.