# Node.js Setup Wizard ended Prematurely on Windows 7 - 64 bit with any versions

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install node-v7.10.0-x64.msi on my windows 64 bit system, it will automatically rolling back at the end. I'm getting same error for other versions as well. [image: Added screenshot here]

I have added my log file also here with. [Log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipf3uqbhzgrtrnu/Nodejs.log?dl=0)

Appreciate any solutions.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20958355/1402230). Your log file contains similar errors as in that answer: 

`WixCreateInternetShortcuts:  Error 0x80040154: failed to save shortcut 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js\Node.js website.url'`

`WixCreateInternetShortcuts:  Error 0x80040154: failed to create Internet shortcut`

`WixSchedInternetShortcuts:  Error 0x8007000d: failed to add temporary row, dberr: 1, err: Directory_`
Also see the other answers to that question.

Comment: @Aule, I tried all of those answers. None of those worked for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I currently don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "performance counter" to "Install when required" during installation

This should let you complete the installation.