# How to fix error when installing node.js on windows 7 32bit

Tags: node.js

For the Screenshot

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/e82Rw.jpg

I can't install node.js [node-v6.10.3-x86.msi], and i trying to search at stackexchange and find this one:
[node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472079/node-js-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely?answertab=active#tab-top)

1. After i follow the instruction and try to "running the MSI" via command prompt as Administator but fails.
2. I try to deleting some registry like this `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib_V2Providers` but didn't take effect

And this the [Logs](https://cdn.rawgit.com/JSilaban/sample/3f1f7027/nodejs.log) on the installation

So what should i do? Thanks a lot

Comment: node has a portable version as well, perhaps you could use that until you figure out the issue.

Comment: where i can got the portable version sir? i search and find on the `sourceforge` but the version is too older

Comment: `https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/` and get the `Windows Binary (.zip) 32 bit`

Comment: Thanks sir, i will try it